# Find and replace L SEP character in HTML

Tags: javascript, regex, sanitize

I have   characters making it into my HTML and I'd like to find and replace them with a bullet (`&bull;`)

I'm using a sanitizer function, but I think I'll need a separate function to find and replace   specifically.

Example string: `Auguste Rodin (1840-1917)   Jeremy Black (1723 - 1756)`

```
Vue.filter("sanitize", function(value) {
  value = String(value);
  value = value.replace(/[^a-z0-9áéíóúñü .,_-]/gim, "").trim();
  return value;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out:

```
value = value.replace(/[\u2028]/g, " \u2022 ");
```

Comment: This fixed my issue too. Thank you!